# Calculating $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} e^{-t\sqrt{n}}\left(1-\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^{-n}$

Tags: limits

For my probability homework I have to show that a certain limit exists and equals $e^{\frac{1}{2}t^2}$.

The limit in question is $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} e^{-t\sqrt{n}}\left(1-\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^{-n}$.

I have tried the following simplifications:
\begin{align*}
 &\quad\ \text{substitute $m = \sqrt{n}$}\\
 &= \lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} e^{-tm}\left(1+\frac{-t}{m}\right)^{-m^2}\\
 &= \lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} e^{-tm}\left(\left(1+\frac{-t}{m}\right)^m\right)^{-m}\\
 &= \lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} e^{-tm}\left(e^{-t}\right)^{-m}\\
 &= \lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} e^{-tm+tm}\\
 &= 1
\end{align*}

But according to wolfram alpha during the third equality the outcome changes.

Can anyone help me on how to properly calculate this limit?

Comment: You can't just calculate the limit for $m \to \infty$ for some of the "inner" terms and leave the rest unchanged. That is like saying $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^2}{n} = n^2 \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating $\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^n\exp(-x\sqrt{n})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165992/calculating-lim-n-to-infty-left1-fracx-sqrtn-rightn-exp-x-sqrt)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluate $\lim\limits_{\alpha \to \infty} e^{-t\sqrt{\alpha}}(1-\frac{t}{\sqrt{\alpha}})^{-\alpha}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1338306/evaluate-lim-limits-alpha-to-infty-e-t-sqrt-alpha1-fract-sqrt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the logarithm which equals
$$
-t\sqrt{n}-n\log\left(1-\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}}\right)=-t\sqrt{n}+n\left(
\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{t^2}{2n}+o(n^{-1})
\right)=\frac{t^2}{2}+o(1)\to t^2/2
$$
as $n\to \infty$ where we used the taylor expansion of $-\log(1-x)=x+\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2)$ in the first equality.

Answer (score 1):

$-t\sqrt n-n\log(1-\frac t {\sqrt n})=-t\sqrt n-n(-\frac t {\sqrt n}-(\frac t {\sqrt n})^{2}/2-... \to t^{2} /2$ so the given limit is $e^{t^{2}/2}$.